# Spring Boot joining two entities with invalid FK entries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am mapping some Java classes using hibernate on a database that I have no write access for. One of the fields used as a FK between ClientEpisodes and Physician's has 6 rows that contain a -1 for the FK. THis is obviously an invalid FK, but I need to still join and simply ignore these Physicians and have a null physician.
I am joining the class using

```
    @JoinColumn(name = "epi_phid1", referencedColumnName = "ph_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    private Physician physician;
```

I tried specifying NO_CONSTRAINT to see if it would ignore it then, but even still I get the following error:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find private.package.info.Physician with id -1
```

Is there any way to tell Hibernate to ignore values that aren't valid such as the -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @ForeignKey annotation with NO_CONSTRAINT value tells hibernate to not generate foreign keys, if schema generation is used. It doesn't have any effect on the internal entity validation in the JPA framework.
There is a hibernate specific **@NotFound** annotation which you could use:

```
 @JoinColumn(name = "epi_phid1", referencedColumnName = "ph_id")
 @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
 private Physician physician;
```

However be advised that if you use this in a @OneToMany or @ManyToMany annotation which maps a Collection, hibernate will fill the invalid/missing entities with null (so the list will contain null value(s)).

Comment: Perfect, thank you for this! Didn't know about this annotation. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/annotations/NotFound.html adding the documentation link for those who end up here in the future.